# only 1 value returns with sql query

Tags: sql-server

AdventureWorks2012 DB - I am trying to return top 1 or 2 emlpoyees from Finance dept and Engineer dept who have worked longest.  I cant get my query to return both, only results from engineering show.  Any suggestions?

```
SELECT TOP 2 EDH.StartDate, E.BusinessEntityID, D.Name, EDH.EndDate, DATEDIFF(hour,EDH.StartDate, GETDATE()) AS HoursWorked
FROM HumanResources.Employee E
INNER JOIN Person.Person PP ON E.BusinessEntityID = PP.BusinessEntityID
INNER JOIN HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory EDH ON E.BusinessEntityID = EDH.BusinessEntityID
INNER JOIN HumanResources.Department D ON D.DepartmentID = EDH.DepartmentID
WHERE (D.Name LIKE 'Finance' OR D.Name = 'Engineering')
AND EDH.EndDate IS NULL
GROUP BY D.Name, EDH.StartDate,E.BusinessEntityID,EDH.EndDate
ORDER BY EDH.StartDate ASC
```

Comment: I don't think that query will run as is.  You have a column in the select clause that isn't in the group by clause, namely `DATEDIFF(hour,EDH.StartDate, GETDATE()) AS HoursWorked`.

Comment: You are filtering out several things here in your WHERE clause.... try checking the table that holds your Finance data and identify a line that you think you should see. Then look at your filters and see if it is being excluded for some reason. Perhaps they have an EndDate? Maybe it's actually listed as 'FINANCE' in the table... Your inner joins work as a filter as well. If you have identified a Finance line but it doesn't have a matching Person record then it will never be returned.

Comment: it runs but all i get is 2001-12-12 3 Engineering NULL 122625
2002-02-06 5 Engineering NULL 121281

Comment: @DanK I think you are right but The Finance dept does contain employees who have a start date. EndDate should be removed in my where filter (IS NULL).

Comment: @roryap that query will work as posted. It is already grouped by EDH.EndDate. It is not required to also group by a computed value when the value inside is already in the group by.

Comment: @SeanLange -- Thanks, I kind of figured that after I pondered it over for a while.

Comment: @SeanLange -- And you meant `EDH.StartDate`, for the purpose of clarity.

Comment: If I say top 20 my results list contains Engineering and Finance in the order of EDH.StartDate.  So somewhere it isnt grouping properly and giving me just 2 Engineering and 2 Finance results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the employees from Engineering happen to have started before the employees from Finance.  The ORDER BY is affecting all of your records (both departments), and then the TOP 2 value is grabbing the two most recent employees, regardless of departments.

If you are trying to write a query that returns the first employee from each department, you're going to have to get a bit more complex.  Here is an example that uses the `ROW_NUMBER()` function to order employees within each department by their start date, then filters those records to only return employees who are the first individuals in their department.

```
SELECT 
    StartDate,
    BusinessEntityID,
    Name,
    EndDate,
    HoursWorked
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
        EDH.StartDate, 
        E.BusinessEntityID, 
        D.Name, 
        EDH.EndDate, 
        DATEDIFF(hour,EDH.StartDate, GETDATE()) AS HoursWorked,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY D.Name ORDER BY EDH.StartDate) AS RowNumberWithinDepartment
    FROM 
        HumanResources.Employee E
         INNER JOIN 
        Person.Person PP ON E.BusinessEntityID = PP.BusinessEntityID
         INNER JOIN 
        HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory EDH ON E.BusinessEntityID = EDH.BusinessEntityID
         INNER JOIN 
        HumanResources.Department D ON D.DepartmentID = EDH.DepartmentID
    WHERE 
        (D.Name LIKE 'Finance' OR D.Name = 'Engineering') AND 
        EDH.EndDate IS NULL
    GROUP BY D.Name, EDH.StartDate,E.BusinessEntityID,EDH.EndDate
  ) x 
WHERE RowNumberWithinDepartment = 1
ORDER BY StartDate ASC
```

Comment: thanks, that worked.  I think there must be a simpler way but i would have to start over.